# Com "echo" funciona e com "return" não

Tags: php, codeigniter, funções

Tenho uma função e ela verifica se a ID informada tem mais de 6 registros no banco de dados. Se tiver, então ela pega, faz um select para retornar esses 6 registros e joga em um array e executa a mesma função, ou seja, função recursiva. Caso tiver menos de 6 registros, então o sistema retorna essa ID informada mesmo.

O problema é o seguinte, quando dou **"return"** ele me exibe "**null"** e quando uso **"echo"** no lugar do **"return"** ele me retorna a ID como deve ser o funcionamento do código.

Estou chamando primeiro assim: `$IDPatrocinador = $this->usuario_model->EscolhePatrocinadorRede(array(55))`

> Eu não quero retornar todos que for menor que 6... Quando eu chamo a
>   função pela primeira vez, passa 1 ID só, então se for menor que 6
>   retorna só ela. Mas se tiver 6 ou mais, então coloco todos em um array
>   para fazer a mesma verificação. Se no primeiro conteúdo do array
>   retornar menor que 6 então não precisa verificar o resto do conteúdo
>   do array. Na verdade preciso só do primeiro a dar menos que 6.

```
public function EscolhePatrocinadorRede($id_patrocinador){

    if(!empty($id_patrocinador)){

        foreach($id_patrocinador as $IDPatrocinador){

            $this->db->where('id_patrocinador', $IDPatrocinador);
            $patrocinadores = $this->db->get('patrocinadores');

            if($patrocinadores->num_rows() < 3){

                return $IDPatrocinador;
            }
        }

        $idUsuario = array();

        foreach($id_patrocinador as $IDPatrocinador){

            $this->db->order_by('id_usuario', 'ASC');
            $this->db->where('id_patrocinador', $IDPatrocinador);
            $patrocinadores = $this->db->get('patrocinadores');

            foreach($patrocinadores->result() as $patrocinador){

                $idUsuario[] = $patrocinador->id_usuario;

            }
        }

        $this->EscolhePatrocinadorRede($idUsuario);
    }
}
```

Comment: porque usa return se o echo que funciona????

Comment: coloque assim `echo $this->usuario_model->EscolhePatrocinadorRede(array(55));`

Comment: Esse metodo está dentro de um controller no Codeigniter???

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não, está dentro de um model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo o raciocínio da minha resposta anterior:

Como você esta chamando a função dentro da própria função, é preciso fazer alguma coisa com o resultado dessa segunda chamada, ou seja retornar para onde a chamou pela primeira vez:

```
public function EscolhePatrocinadorRede($id_patrocinador){

    if(!empty($id_patrocinador)){

        foreach($id_patrocinador as $IDPatrocinador){

            $this->db->where('id_patrocinador', $IDPatrocinador);
            $patrocinadores = $this->db->get('patrocinadores');

            if($patrocinadores->num_rows() < 3){

                return $IDPatrocinador;
            }
        }

        $idUsuario = array();

        foreach($id_patrocinador as $IDPatrocinador){

            $this->db->order_by('id_usuario', 'ASC');
            $this->db->where('id_patrocinador', $IDPatrocinador);
            $patrocinadores = $this->db->get('patrocinadores');

            foreach($patrocinadores->result() as $patrocinador){

                $idUsuario[] = $patrocinador->id_usuario;

            }
        }
        // estava faltando esse return para mandar o resultado para onde ocorreu a primeira chamada da função
        return $this->EscolhePatrocinadorRede($idUsuario);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado!. Era isso mesmo. Tão simples que não vi. Muito obrigado Jader!

Answer (score 2):

Toda função deve fazer ou retornar alguma coisa, isso parece obvio, mas é exatamente onde você esta se confundindo.

Quando você chama a função assim:

```
<?php    
$this->usuario_model->EscolhePatrocinadorRede(array(55));
?>
```

e lá dentro dela você tem:

```
...
return $IDPatrocinador;
...
```

a sua função serve para atribuir um valor para `$IDPatrocinador` e em seguida retornar esse valor ao escopo que a chamou, então se ela retornar o valor `123` por exemplo, é o mesmo que:

```
<?php
123;
?>
```

ou seja, não esta fazendo absolutamente nada com o valor retornado pela função.

Agora, se você chamar a função assim:

```
<?php    
echo $this->usuario_model->EscolhePatrocinadorRede(array(55));
?>
```

será o mesmo que:

```
<?php
echo 123;
?>
```

logo, vai imprimir o valor como desejado.

Comment: Fiz com o echo como você falou **echo $this->usuario_model->EscolhePatrocinadorRede(array(55));** e não retorna nada se eu uso **return**

Comment: Provavelmente sua primeira consulta está retornando mais de 2 registros, então mais abaixo você chama a própria função só que não esta fazendo nada com o retorno... Adicione um return na frente dessa segunda chamada da propria função...

Comment: Na verdade a sua função está mais complicada do que deveria, e com possibilidade de entrar em loop, sugiro que faça uma otimização na estrutura e impossibilite que ela entre em loop.